# What factors can affect different containers processing on one machine at the same time?

Tags: docker, networking, containers

For example, I have a 4vCPU, 8GB mem VM. At first, I ran a Nginx container on it and then used a stress test tool to continuously send requests to it and got some information like QPS, average latency. Then I ran three same Nginx containers on the VM and parallelly send the same requests above to these containers.I found that the respective QPS all decreased, and average latency all increased.

So what factors can affect different containers processing on one machine at the same time? I think the CPU and memory are enough to provide resources to these containers. What factors below the docker can affect these, firstly I think is network, but what else? And Specifically, why can network affect these QPS, average latency metrics?

Comment: This is not a programming question. Not even remotely.

Comment: Ah...Where can I ask the question?

Comment: ServerFault would be a better place.